# CRM SDK OrganizationServiceContext null navigation properties on entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

Trying to migrate an existing solution away from the deprecated Microsoft.Xrm.Client namespace to just use the generated service context from `CrmSvcUtil` using CrmSDK 9.0.0.5.

Previously we were using `Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization` to get a lazily loaded context.

I have two copies of the same solution and have been working through some of the API changes.

I have enabled Proxy Types

```
client.OrganizationServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
```

Which to my understanding switched it to act in a lazily-loaded manner. However, none of the navigation properties are loading as expected.

The few blog posts that I've found around this shift to `CrmServiceClient` etc suggest that even without lazy loading I should be able to load the property manually with a call to `Entity.LoadProperty()` which will either load the property or refresh the data. However, after doing that the navigation property is still null (specifically I'm trying to use a Contact navigation property). When I look through the `RelatedEntities` collection it is also empty.

I know that the entity has a related contact item as if I use a context generated with `Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization` it returns it and I can also see it in CRM itself using an advanced search.

```
var connectionUri = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Xrm"].ConnectionString;
var client = new CrmServiceClient(connectionUri);
client.OrganizationServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
var context = new XrmServiceContext(client);

var result = context.new_applicationSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.new_applicantid.Id == CurrentUserId);
//result.Contact is null
context.LoadProperty(result, "Contact");
//result.Contact is still null
//result.RelatedEntities is empty
```

Comment: I checked you code on my instance and it works without a problem. I'm using the latest XrmTooling and the latest Xrm.SDK (both 9.0.0.7). Maybe try to update the version of your SDK? Also I don't know if that is a problem with your example but in your code you are selecting all the attributes of new_application entity. Therefore all existing values will be already there so LoadProperty will not change anything in this case - if it's null in the first place, it will be null after the call

Comment: And you don't need to do `client.OrganizationServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes()` Xrm.Tooling does this for you by default.